# How to solve mysql 23000 duplicate entry error

Tags: mysql, duplicates

I am getting the 1062(23000) Duplicate Entry error on insert.
It's structure is like this,

V_main

```
CR     vachar(3)
PO     int(11)
RF     varchar(100)
Alt    varchar(100)
sample varchar(100)
and further
```

All these 5 fields together make the Primary key. and sample is foreign key from sample_main.
There are actual duplicate records. The CR field can have multiple similar value so I can't keep in unique. 
I really am not sure what i am missing here,
Thanks,
Vrunda

Comment: you cannot have two records with the same Primary key. so if you need to have duplicates, do not use a Primary key (or change the definition of Primary key)

Comment: Thanks Gilles Gouaillardet for quick reply. I'll see if I can change the structure of the table. While creating the table I created the primary key like this -> Primary key(CR,PO,RF,ALT,Sample). Is this right? My thinking was that this whole combination acts as one whole one key and so it shouldn't be bothered by duplicates.